# Find X for matrix $A(X-I)^{-1} = B^t$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

> In an exam I had to find $X$ for $A(X-I)^{-1} = B^t$.

**I did it this way:**
\begin{align}
& A(X-I)^{-1}(X-I) = B^t(X-I) \\
\implies & A I = B^t(X-I) \\
\implies & A = B^t(X-I) \\
\implies & B^tA = B^tB^t(X-I) \\
\implies & B^{-1}B^tA = B^{-1}B(X-I) \\
\implies & B^{-1}B^tA = (X-I) \\
\implies & B^{-1}B^tA = X-I \\
\implies & B^{-1}B^tA+I = X \\
\implies & X = B^{-1}B^tA+I.
\end{align}
My teacher told me that this is wrong, but didn't give any explanation what did I do wrong.

From other students I found out that the right answer was $X = (A^{-1}B^t)^{-1}+I$

But if I will use this answer:
\begin{align}
& X = (A^{-1}B^t)^{-1}+I$ / (open $( )^{-1}$) \\
\implies & X = (B^t)^{-1}(A^{-1})^{-1}+I \\
\implies & X = (B^t)^{-1}A+I \\
\implies & X = (B^t)^{-1}A+I  / (B^t)^{-1} = (B^{-1})^t \\
\implies & X = B^{-1}B^tA+I / (B^{-1})^t = B^{-1}B^t \\
\implies & X = B^{-1}B^tA+I.
\end{align}
And I get the same answer. Did I miss something, where is my mistake?

Comment: What does the open mean?

Comment: You started in a wrong fashion, multiplying the left side of the equation by $X-I$ but leaving the right side of the equation unchanged.

Comment: @hardmath sorry it forgot to type it. I i typed it now on my answer.

Comment: **Tip for your next exam:** First, suppose that these matrices are $1\times 1$ and solve the equation over the reals. Then redo the computation for the general case and take care that matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: What does the first line of your answer mean?

Comment: Next problem: in the implications $$A = B^t(X-I)
\implies B^tA = B^tB^t(X-I)\implies B^{-1}B^tA = B^{-1}B(X-I)$$ the first one is unneeded and the second one is wrong.

Comment: @Did $(B^t)^t = B$ ?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik  $(A^{−1}B^t)^{−1} = (B^t)^{−1}(A^{−1})^{−1}$

Comment: I take it that you’re allowed to assume that $A$ and $B$ are invertible?

Comment: Again, from $$B^tA = B^tB^t(X-I)$$ one can deduce that $$B^{-1}B^tA = B^{-1}B^tB^t(X-I)$$ not that $$B^{-1}B^tA = B^{-1}B(X-I)$$

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is $B^tB^t = B$ which you use in both derivations. $B^tB^t$ is not the same as $(B^t)^t$; and in general $B^tB^t \not= B$.

First here:
$$
B^tA = B^tB^t(X-I) \\
\implies B^{-1}B^tA = B^{-1}B(X-I)
$$

And a second time here:
$$
\implies X = B^{-1}B^tA+I / (B^{-1})^t = B^{-1}B^t 
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
A(X-I)^{-1} &=& B^T \\
(X-I)^{-1} = A^{-1} B^T \\
X-I = (A^{-1}B^T)^{-1} \\
X = I+(A^{-1}B^T)^{-1} \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: My question was why $X=I+(A^{−1}B^T)^{−1}=B^T$ not $X=B^{−1}B^tA+I$

and where was I wrong...